# Persistant storage for unpacked Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, localforage

I'm trying to use a kind of storage to persist some state for unpacked chrome extension, but I'm noticing that both localForage localStorage resets itself when I remove the extension and reload it into the extensions page in Google Chrome.

Are there any other storage options or methods which will persist storage even if the extension is removed from your Chrome's extensions?

Comment: No, there's no such storage. You can use an external storage like dropbox or call a local utility via nativeMessaging, however the simplest solution is to not remove the extension: you only need to click the reload icon on the card in chrome://extensions page to reload it.